# LIBSVM output regarding model.SVs

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

I am new to libsvm. I am having trouble understanding the output of libsvm. I just want to know how do you find the alpha_i of all the support vectors? Does the parameter `model.sv_coef` give you the `alpha_i` or `alpha_i*y_i`? and the other main question that I wanted to ask is what does `model.SVs` give? I am using libsvm in matlab and the output I am getting when I look for `model.SVs` is:

my training set is:

```
-1 1:0.747253 2:0.894737     
+1 1:0.692308 2:-0.824561     
-1 1:0.362637 2:0.789474     
+1 1:0.769231 2:-0.321637
```

my test set:

```
-1 1:-0.351648 2:-0.602339

+1 1:-0.21978 2:-0.263158



var1=model.sv_indices

>>var1 =

     2
     4
     3



model.SVs

>>ans =



(1,1)       2.0000    
(2,1)       4.0000    
(3,1)       3.0000   
(1,2)      -0.2204    
(2,2)       0.2870    
(3,2)       0.9774   
(1,3)       1.1592   
(2,3)       0.7978    
(3,3)      -0.3999   
(1,4)      -0.3999    
(2,4)       0.0250   
(3,4)       0.7548   
(1,5)       0.7978    
(2,5)       0.6952    
(3,5)       0.0250
```

what are these (1,1),(2,1),(3,1)...? I mean I have only 4 training set so how can this second index go to 5 and only two test set so how can the first index go to 3.

Answer (score 2):

`model.sv_coef` contains all the `alpha_i * y_i`, `model.SVs` are all the support vectors `x_i`. The weights can be written as

```
w = model.SVs' * model.sv_coef;
b = -model.rho;
```

You may not need to care much about the labeling of (1,2), (1,3)...`m.nSV` will give you the number of support vectors for each class. Since you have only two classes, the answer should be a `2*1` vector with each row representing the support vector number for the corresponding class. Check this [document](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f804) for more details.